# Python palindrome function; is it possible to write it without using string conversion?

Tags: python, strings, mathematics, palindrome

I hope this question is okay to ask on Code Review; this is a little function I wrote in Python 2.7.12 that checks if a number is a palindrome. It works fine but I'd like to know if there is a purely mathematical way to do it without using string conversion.

Here is the function:

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    forward = str(n)
    backward = []

    i = len(forward) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        backward.append(forward[i])
        i -= 1

    backward = "".join(backward)

    if backward == forward:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

How would one go about solving such a problem without using string conversion?

Comment: `divmod(12345, 10)` → `1234, 5`